# How can I delete few files from a directory at restart of my OS before getting logged ? I am using ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: server, 19.10

I created a file rc.local in etc folder and one process start by using this file which works smoothly. I just Additional add one line to remove few files from dir my code as follows

```
#!/bin/sh -e
ads start
exit 0
```

This works well and each time system restart my process starts. Now I add a line after my process like this

```
#!/bin/sh -e
ads start
rm /dataTemp/*.tmp
exit 0
```

This works for a single restart , if I restart the system again rc.local never loads.

I use

```
sudo service rc.local start
```

to start the service when it fails each time.

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Why have you tagged 14.04 if you are using 19.10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a Cronjob that will run on boot.
from your terminal type

```
crontab -e
```

Then add the `@reboot` to your `rm /dataTemp/*.tmp` command to your cronjob list
for example `@reboot rm /dataTemp/*.tmp` .